# Python: Using one argument to handle choice between a number and a string?

Tags: python

Basically I am writing a function that depends on a numerical input x, a number between 0 and 1. I want the default value of x to be, say, x=0.5. However, I also want to provide an option to the user that allows them to let the program select x for them using some algorithm. Is there an elegant way to handle that choice with one function argument?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
def foo(x=0.5):
    if x == "pick for me":
        return complicated_algorithm_that_picks_x()
    else:
        return x

def complicated_algorithm_that_picks_x():
    print "Thinking hard..."
    return 0.1234567
```

which would return:

```
>>> foo()
0.5
>>> foo(0.3)
0.3
>>> foo("pick for me")
Thinking hard...
0.1234567
```

But this looks really inelegant, since the user has to know what magic string to pass to invoke the selection algorithm. Any ideas how I can handle this more cleanly?

I was thinking having an additional Boolean argument called pick (that defaults to False), which when True will invoke the x picking function. But then users might pass both, say, x=0.3 and pass=True, in which case I have to arbitrarily ignore one of the choices. Looks clumsy again.

Comment: Why not just have two separate functions?

Comment: do you plan on adding more alternatives, or just the one 'pick for me'?

Comment: I don't see any way to do not know how to use your function. In any case the user must know the 'pick for me' value, or the pick argument.

What about run complicated_algorithm_that_picks_x if x < 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things you might consider:

1. Split the one function into two.
2. Use a class.
3. Multiple default arguments.

Here there are, in no particular order:

### Split one function into two

If you want to do two different things in one function and you're having trouble designing a natural interface, it might be a sign that the one function should become two:

```
def foo_picked_for_me():
    x = pick_x()
    return foo(x)

def foo(x):
    # do foo
    pass
```

I don't know how this strikes you, but it's simple, clear, and that means its often preferable.

### Use a class

Default arguments are nice, but a function's interface can only get so complicated before it starts making more sense to handle option setting with a class:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0.5

    def pick_x_for_me(self):
        self.x = pick_x()

    def foo(self):
        # do foo with self.x
```

As EOL suggests below, it's perfectly pythonic to leave `x` "exposed", and to allow the user to change it. You say, though, that `x` must be between 0 and 1, so it might make sense to do some bounds checking with the setter for `x`:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0.5

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if 0 <= value <= 1:
            self._x = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("x must be between 0 and 1")

    def pick_x_for_me(self):
        self._x = pick_x()

    def foo(self):
        pass
        # do foo with self._x
```

### Multiple default arguments

The last option is analogous to what other posters have given: use two arguments, and throw an exception if the user does something contradictory. I'd consider allowing three forms of call:

```
    # x gets its default value of 0.5
    foo()

    # x gets the specified value
    foo(x=.42)

    # x is picked for me
    foo(pick_for_me=True)
```

Additionally, if I write:

```
foo(x=.42, pick_for_me=True)
```

I'll throw an exception. Some code that implements this follows:

```
def foo(x=None, pick_for_me=None):
    if x is None and pick_for_me is None:
        x = 0.5
    elif pick_for_me and x:
        raise RuntimeError("You can't set both!")
    elif pick_for_me:
        x = picking_algorithm()

    # else x was set, so leave it be
```

This is kind of complicated, and I'm not so sure I like the API. Just make sure you document the behavior well enough so that the user knows how to use the thing.

Comment: I agree with the "create two functions" approach. The class implementation is too complicated: there should be no `set_x()` method (or at the very least `x` should be a property), and `_x` should be `x`, since it can be modified by the user.

Comment: @eol 'x' should be a property, but this is just for exposition. For more complicated combinations of options a class might make sense, but I agree that here it's largely overkill.

Comment: The class can make sense, I have no problem with that. Just that the `set_x` itself complicates things unnecessarily, in Python (`set_x` should be removed altogether and `_x` should be `x`, in Python).

Comment: Thanks for presenting all the most reasonable choices together. I like the class implementation the best -- it won't be an overkill for me because my function is actually one within a class.

But is it fair to say that just having x instead of _x and set_x() is a more Pythonic way of doing things? That Python users are generally receptive to modifying object.x directly? I'm still relatively new to Python so am not completely in tune with the conventions.

Comment: Yep, EOL is right in that it's more pythonic to let the user set `x` directly. I changed the first class example to reflect that. I also added a second class example that uses python's `property` and `setter` decorators to do some bounds checking. With the second example, you can write code like `foo.x = .4` to set `x`, and if you write `foo.x = 42` an exception will be thrown, since `x` is not in-bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably define a constant in the module that indicates to generate a random value. For example:

```
# foo.py
import random

RANDOM = 'random'

def foo(x=0.5):
    if x == RANDOM:
        x = random.random()
    if x < 0 or x > 1:
        raise ValueError('x must be between 0 and 1')
    return x
```

Then, to use it is pretty straightforward:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.foo(0.1)
0.1
>>> foo.foo()
0.5
>>> foo.foo(foo.RANDOM)
0.4388309758578337
>>> foo.foo(foo.RANDOM)
0.5351558099071574
>>> foo.foo(7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 9, in foo
    raise ValueError('x must be between 0 and 1')
ValueError: x must be between 0 and 1
```

Comment: There should definitely be an `else` after `if x == RANDOM`, because it there is no need to be inefficient and non-explicit. Also `if x < 0 or x > 1` would be more direct as `if not (0 <= x <= 1)`.

Comment: Disagree on else clause. Avoid extraneous condition clauses when they're not necessary.

Comment: And I generally will prefer comparison chaining like you suggest, but I actually find `not (0 <= x <= 1)` *less* readable than `x < 0 or x > 1`.

Comment: Not using `elif` is arguably not a good design principle: (1) This makes the code slower for no reason (which is generally not desireable). (2) You are forcing your readers to parse all subsequent `if` clauses just to see if they will trigger, thus making understanding your code harder (longer) and hiding your intent (which is to implement the Python equivalent of C's `case`).

Comment: I prefer the sanity check of the valid range, even knowing the return value of `random.random` will always be in the desired range.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I prefer unit tests to sanity checks, as the checks make the code slower; also, there is no indication that your second test is a sanity check, it may well just be just a regular `if`; finally, the sanity check should probably be put inside the function which is checked, then, so as to follow the Don't Repeat Yourself principle (in case the function checked is called in more than one place).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def foo(x=0.5, use_complex_algo=False):
    if use_complex_algo == False:
        return x
    else:
        return complicated_algorithm_that_picks_x()

#ouput
print foo()                         # returns: 0.5
print foo(0.3)                      # returns:  0.3
print foo(use_complex_algo=True)    # returns: 0.1234567
```

Comment: This doesn't preclude passing *both* `x` and `use_complex_algo=True`. Your else clause is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code would do what all you want!

```
import random

def foo(x=0.5):
  if x=="pick for me":
    return random.random()
  else:
    return x


print foo()
print foo("pick for me")
print foo(0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parameter type passed is float (can also be checked), you could define that any input < 0 or > 1 means "pick for me"... 
It also kind of validates that the passed parameter is within range, and if not generates a proper value.

But this does not really answer the question about choosing between a number & a string  ;-) (type() could help for this)

```
def foo(x=0.5):
    if 0 <= x <= 1:
        return x
    else:
        return complicated_algorithm_that_picks_x()
```